# How can I delete menus in Glade?

Tags: menu, programming, quickly, glade

I'm writing a program using Quickly and I can't figure out how to delete menu bar entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 different ways to edit the menu items. Note that these steps also work for a toolbar and partially for a treeview too.

### Option 1

1. Select the menu by clicking on it in the editor (A) or search for it in the widget tree (B).
2. A new Glade toolbar button will appear at the end with an "Edit" icon. Click that to bring up a new dialog where you can change the entries.
3. In the "Hierarchy" tab you'll see all entries which can be added/removed/edited.

[image]

[image]

### Option 2

1. Search and select the menubar in the widget tree
2. Unfold the child widgets
3. These are your menu entries. Select them to bring up their properties in the property editor and edit them as you would with all other wisgets. Right click to bring up options including removal.